# SSAS Cube (Multidimensional) - Unknown table

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have created a datawarehouse database in an Ms SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition. I can process the cube and everything works fine.

Now I have an consultant helping me adding extra dimensions to my datawarehouse. She has a copy of the database on her MS SQL Server 2012 Standard edition.

She has created a brand new Cube (multidimensional) project on our Test site (also Enterprise edition) where she uses some of the old dimensions (views) from the datawarehouse database as well as the new dimensions she created (also views). The Cube project she has created is created up against our test-environment with and SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition Analysis server.

The strange thing is that when she tries to process an old dimension it works fine. But when she tries to process a new dimension it fails.

The error is:

```
DimensionAttribute [Vdim Contract Location Company].[Contract Location Company Key] : The KeyColumn #0 refers to 'edw_vdim_ContractLocationCompany', an unknown table, in the 'OnTrack' DataSourceView.
```

The strange thing is that we can explore the data from the Cube project. But when we try to process it, it cannot find it?

Comment: Verify the user the SSAS account is running under can indeed access the database, using the connection string configured for the "OnTrack" DSV (and that it connects to the correct database -- including things like DNS aliases).

Answer (score 0):

From the error description - your dimension is referring a table which is missing in DSV. I would do the following to find out error cause:

- Check that referred table is present in the DSV, and you can see data when you choose "Explore Data" in SSMS dimension designer, and check this in DSV designer as well
- If table is present in DSV - try to do a complete deploy of your project, not a differential deploy. This is set in Project - Settings menu.
- If still no success - delete erroneous attribute from the dimension or dimension itself, deploy the project. Then add the deleted attribute or dimension back and redeploy the project. This will clean up obsolete metadata from the project.

The error has little to do with version of your Environment

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I can see the data in "Explore Data". Making a complete deploy does not do the trick either. Have also deleted the cube from the server and deployed again with no luck.

Comment: @olf, try to delete dimension attribute `Contract Location Company Key`, deploy and process the dimension. Then -- recreate this attribute and process again.

Comment: Ferdipux, that did the trick! Removed the whole dimension, deployed, added the dimension and redeployed. Please submit an answer with your solution and I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Datasource in the consultant's SSAS database (in the test environment) is still pointing to the live source database.  Which of course won't have the new tables/views.

Check the connection string in SSMS.
If it is pointing to the right place, check the settings under ImpersonationInfo.  Could be that permissions to SELECT from those new views/tables hasn't been granted to the login being used.